# SSRS indicators setting of values and states

Tags: reporting-services

I am tryding to achieve this :

[image]

When the column "verwag" is equal to "skatting", I want a yellow flat line, if it is greater than skatting I want a green arrow and when it is smaller than skatting I want a red arrow. I cannot figure out how to set the value and state in the indicator properties to achieve this.

Regards

Comment: Do you calculate verwag and skatting columns? Or are you using the fields in the tablix directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming those columns are just fields called skatting and verwag; set the Expression for the value to:

```
=Switch(Fields!verwag.Value > Fields!skatting.Value, 1, Fields!verwag.Value = Fields!skatting.Value, 2, Fields!verwag.Value < Fields!skatting.Value, 3)
```

And then set the states like this:

[image]